# How to print empty String Array

Tags: java, json, string, arraylist

I'm trying to read data from .dat files & then write them in .json. The problem is some persons have no emails in files. So, I want something like

> "emails": []

```
 {
    "personCode": "2342",
    "firstName": "Jeff",
    "lastName": "Spalding",
    "address": {
      "street": "123 Friendly Street",
      "city": "Ottawa",
      "state": "ON",
      "zip": "K1A 0G9",
      "country": "Canada"
    },
    "emails": []
  },
```

However, my code prints no emails[]

```
{
  "personCode": "2342",
  "firstName": "Jeff",
  "lastName": "Spalding",
  "address": {
    "street": "123 Friendly Street",
    "city": "Ottawa",
    "state": "ON",
    "zip": "K1A 0G9",
    "country": "Canada"
  }
}
```

My code:

```
String[] email = null;
    String[] emailTokens = data[3].split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < emailTokens.length; i++) {
             email = emailTokens;
        }

Person person = new Person(personCode, firstName, lastName, address, email);
    personList.add(person);
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think you need the empty `emails` field?  Can't you just check if that field be null in the corresponding Java JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop doesn't make sense:

```
for (int i = 0; i < emailTokens.length; i++) {
    email = emailTokens;  // Here you assign the some emailTokens N times.
}
```

It can be simplified to:

```
String[] email = data[3].split(",");
```

Regarding your question about missed email in the JSON, try to pass empty array:

```
String[] email = data[3].split(",");
if (email == null) {
    email = new String[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found another way by using ArrayList<String> emailList = new ArrayList<String>(); if (data.length == 4).